# ServerValue.TIMESTAMP firestore in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

how can i get the current date "day-time" in my document in firestore
as i wanna display photos set or[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrMog.png)dered by name .
this way doesnt work

> Kotlin

```
class Data( var urlList: MutableList<String>,var time: MutableMap<String, String>) {
    constructor() : this(ArrayList(),  ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is only used with Realtime Database.  You need [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#serverTimestamp()) instead for Firestore.

Comment: what's the type of this variable should be?

Comment: If you click the link, it'll take you to the API docs.